# AsyncStorage store empty array after API fetch React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I try to store data with AsyncStorage after fetch

```
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await url.get(`/../`);
          data = response.data;
          if (data.length) {
            setItems(data)
            storeData(); 
          }
        } catch(error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      };


      const storeData = async () => {
        try {
            const data = JSON.stringify(items);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, data);
        } catch (error) {
            alert('Error')
        }
      };
```

I call function fetchData with button. When i click first time, Asyncstorage store empty array.
On the second click it store an array.

```
<Button title="fetch data" onPress={fetchData} />
```

As much as i understood, it works asynchronously, but what should i change in this code to store data at first click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setItems(data`) is async , so you cant guarentee when the data will be set to state, a rather better approach would be like this :

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await url.get(`/../`);
          data = response.data;
          if (data.length) {
            setItems(data)
            storeData(data); 
          }
        } catch(error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      };


      const storeData = async (data) => {
        try {
            const data1 = JSON.stringify(data);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, data1);
        } catch (error) {
            alert('Error')
        }
      };
```

here im passing the data to storeData and setting that value, hope it helps. please feel free for doubts

Comment: i've marked of course. Could you please say, is there a way to store a state, not response.data? For example, when i should to push response.data to an existing array ```setItems(...items, data)```

Comment: means>? couldnt get it

Comment: e.g. i have an array with items, i'd like to fetch more items and put them to array with items. I make it with ```setItems(...items, data)```. I'd like to store a new array with AsyncStorage. When i store only response.data ```storeData(data)```, existing items are not saved